# C code - a way to convert 5 to 7 and 7 to 5 without "if"

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, low-level, low-level-code

I want to write a function that gets a number X and if X=5 it returns 7 , if X=7 it return 5 otherwise, return something else.
There is the trivial way - to use "if" blocks
Another way - to use a map (5 mapped to 7, 7 mapped to 5)
Third way - to write the matching linear mathematical equation 
BUT I'm looking for the 4th way of doing it (again - without using "if" blocks at all).

It feels like I need to use bit operation but I'm not dominant in this area so I need help.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: By `if` you mean `if`, `switch` and ternary operators alltogether (i.e. no form of branching at all)?

Comment: Yes. No if, no switch etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int fun(int p)
{
    return p^2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As well as the obvious bitwise XOR solution, you can also exploit the fact that a boolean expression returns 1 or 0, e.g.

```
int f(int x)
{
    return (x == 5) * 7 + (x == 7) * 5;
}
```

and there are other simple arithmetic methods, e.g.

```
int f(int x)
{
    return 12 - x;
}
```

Comment: The first one is still some kind of "if" BUT I really like the 12-X.
Simple, clean and straightforward.
I should have tought about it :=)

Comment: The first one is actually branchless in general - try compiling it and look at the generated code.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is no homework I do for you:

```
int mysteriousFunction( int x ) {
    return (x ^ 2);
}
```

Comment: It's OK - this is not homework, just a challange to give different solutions to one problem and to think in different ways

Answer (score 0):

if input range is bounded and small, use input as index into a lookup table of results...